# Complex numbers : How to decide what the 'correct' angle is when evaluating complex numbers in their polar form?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates, angle

$z = \cos Q + i \sin Q$

Find $z+1$ in polar form.

$R$, the magnitude, I've worked out to be $2 \cos \frac{Q}{2}$

In its polar form, $z+1 = 2 \cos \frac{Q}{2}$ $( \cos x + i\sin x)$

$\tan x = \frac{\sin Q}{1+\cos Q }$

I get:

$\tan x = \tan \frac{Q}{2}$

Now, $x= \pi + \frac{Q}{2}$, or $x=\frac{Q}{2}$.

How do I know what the correct answer is?

Comment: We need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question.  Here's a mediocre hint:  You should be able to say something about the real part of $z$.  It can't take on just any value.  This will tell you enough about $Re(z+1)$ to decide in which quadrant(s) your $x$ can lie.

Comment: Hmm.. if I have a random complex number in the first quadrant, z, then z+1 is still in the first quadrant, but with a reduced angle, as the real part has increased. So.. it's x= Q/2?

Comment: Think about the cos function?  What can you say about its value?  Write that as in inequality.  Add 1.  What does that tell you about where $Re(z+1)$ can be found.  Knowing which quadrant(s) $z+1$ lies in tells you which arguments are possible.

Comment: -1 <Cos Q < 1 , so 0 < Cos Q + 1 < 2 
So it lies in either the 1st or 4th quadrant

Since we don't have the 4th as an option, we go with the first?

Comment: Mostly correct but 4th quadrant is an option.  I think for $0\le Q<\pi, x=\frac{Q}{2}$, but for $\pi<Q<2\pi, x=\pi+\frac{Q}{2}$.  You have a point on the unit circle, and you're moving the point one unit to the right.  Everything ends up in the first or fourth quadrants (except $Q=\pi$ which goes to $x=0$).

Comment: Um, now I'm confused. The actual question is about using the binomial expansion of (1+z)^n to find an expression for (nC1) Cos Q + (nC2) Cos2Q ... + (nCn) Cos nQ, by considering the real part of (1+z)^n . If I evaluate x 'piecewise', how would I obtain the answer?

Comment: That is tricky.  I'm not sure I have a great answer, so I suggest sweeping the whole thing under the rug.  Define $Q=\arg{z}$ to lie in $(-\pi,\pi)$.  Then no matter which quadrant $z$ lies in, $\frac{Q}{2}$ is correct for $\arg{(z+1)}$  Note that for even powers $n$ it wouldn't matter whether you took $\frac{Q}{2}$ or $\frac{Q}{2}+\pi$ after applying DeMoivre's Theorem.  I don't see what to do about the odd powers though.

Comment: I don't understand. What does defining Q as arg z do? Isn't that already the case?

Comment: If you specify the range of $Q=\arg{z}$ to be $(-\pi,\pi)$, that fixes arg$(z+1)$ as $\frac{Q}{2}$  Think about a point in each of the four quadrants.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is more widespread than just complex variables and just tangent. That's why most, if not all, programming languages distinguish between and ordinary arctangent, say atan(y/x) and one that accounts for the quadrant, as in atan2(y,x). A similar problem happened to me recently when I was using the law of sines; all my obtuse angles were coming out as acute. That was because $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$.